# java Finding 1's complement

Tags: java, arrays

Write a recursive program that takes a string of length N containing only 0’s and 1’s as input and 
performs a 1’s complement on the binary number specified in the string. An example of how the 
program should transform a given input is given here:

> Input: 010001001 → 110001001 → 100001001 → … 101110110 (output)

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdOut;

public class labb1q1b {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String b = "010001001";
        StdOut.print(invert(b));
    }


    public static String invert(String input) 
    {

        String temp = "";
        for(int i = input.length(); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            temp += Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow isn't here to do your home work for you, but we can answer specific questions to help you complete it yourself. try editing your question to be more specific

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) does work here, hypothetically.  But it behaves wrongly with invalid inputs, eg `'A'` (returns `10`), or `'$'` (returns `-1`).  For future reference, it could hypothetically be used, but it is preferable to read it this way.

Here's the fix: You want to check the character at the specific point, and if it is `'0'`, add `"1"`, otherwise, add `"0"`.

Use this:

```
    public static String invert(String input) 
    {

        String temp = "";

        //Iterate thru all of the characters in the string, in order of first to last
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            if (input.charAt(i) == '0') {
                temp += "1";
            } else {
                temp += "0";
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Also, note that I have swapped the order the `for` loop runs in.  This keeps the string from being reversed, and also keeps an out of bounds error from occurring.

Comment: thanx, but could i use:

Comment: @dvdvd "Could I use" what?  You mean this code?  Yea, just credit that this method was `Suggested by Pokechu22`.

Comment: `temp += input.charAt(i) == '0' ? "1" : "0";` save yourself a few lines

Comment: @VinceEmigh That is certainly legal, but in this case, I went for a wider solution that's easy to understand at first glance.  Also, you forgot singlequotes around the 0.  It should be `temp += input.charAt(I) == '0' ? "1" : "0";`.

Comment: [`Character.getNumericaValue('0')` evaluates to `0`](http://ideone.com/Eysomq). Your answer rests on a falsehood.

Comment: You appear to be correct; [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) are stating that it does work as a parse system, but for things like 'A' returning 10.  It's not the optimal function for this case, at least with a binary string.  But I will edit my answer to note that.

Comment: String concatenation like this (using `+=` on string in a loop) will be quite slow, you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for better performance.

Comment: @kajacx I know of that as well.  I didn't use it here for simplicity reasons, but I suppose I can just change this to a community wiki and you people can improve it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

That is not recursing. To recurse you use the method inside of the same method. in your case you would call invert() inside of it to continuously edit the string, same thing as a for loop pretty much though.